# Does or does Task.Wait not start the task if it isn't already running?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

According to the Microsoft TPL documentation I read ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/10/15/task-wait-and-inlining/)) calling the `Task.Wait()` method will block the current thread until that task finishes (or cancels, or faults). But it also said that if the task in question hadn't started yet, the `Wait` method will attempt to run it *on its own thread* by asking the scheduler to reassign it, thus reducing the amount of wastage due to blocking.

I've got a system in which tasks (once running) begin by collecting data by starting other tasks and waiting on their results. These other tasks in turn begin by collecting data from yet other tasks and-so-on-and-so-fort, potentially a few hundred layers deep. I *really* don't want umpteen tasks blocking and waiting for the one task at the end to finally finish.

However when I tried this out in a test console app, `Task.Wait()` doesn't seem to start anything at all.

What are the correct incantations for building a sequence of tasks that must all wait on each other with a minimum of wasted cycles? It's sort of like ContinueWith, except starting with the last task in the series...

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
      var token = source.Token;

      // Create a non-running task.
      var task = new Task<string[]>(() => InternalCompute(token), token);

      // Isn't this supposed to start the task?
      task.Wait(CancellationToken.None);

      // I realise this code now won't run until the task finishes,
      // it's here for when I use task.Start() instead of task.Wait().
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to cancel the process.");
      Console.ReadKey(true);
      source.Cancel();
      Console.WriteLine("Source cancelled...");

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit.");
      Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    private static string[] InternalCompute(CancellationToken token)
    {
      string[] data;
      try
      {
        data = Compute(token);
      }
      catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
      {
        return null;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return new[] { ex.Message };
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Post-processor starting.");
      for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        if (data[i] is null)
          Console.WriteLine($"Null data at {i}.");
        else
          Console.WriteLine($"Valid data at {i}.");
      Console.WriteLine("Post-processor completed.");
      return data;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method stands in for an abstract one to be implemented by plug-in developers.
    /// </summary>
    private static string[] Compute(CancellationToken token)
    {
      var data = new string[10];
      for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
      {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        data[i] = i.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine($"Computing item {i + 1}...");
      }
      return data;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Run() instead? Task.Run(() => <methodname>());

Comment: according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.7.2), `Task.Wait()` ***only*** makes the `Task` wait, nothing more.  you'll need to use `Task.Run()` or `Task.Start()`.

Comment: Also, if you aren't using async you don't need tasks nor CancellationToken.

Comment: @Tau, found the document I read before: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/10/15/task-wait-and-inlining/

Comment: @fstam, if I first Run() the task, and then Wait() for the task, doesn't the tread my current code in on block until the task finishes on some other thread? If so, I'd like to avoid that as often as possible.

Comment: @fstam, "Also, if you aren't using async you don't need tasks nor CancellationToken." I'm pretty sure CancellationTokens work just fine without async. You only need async if you want to use the await keyword, but you can still use tasks and tokens without those.

Comment: Your method is not Async, therefore you can not await the run call. Calling run without await will run the task on the same thread.

Comment: @DavidRutten CancellationTokens can be used but will never work in practice. You can't call Cancel on a task if the only running thread IS the task you want to cancel.

Comment: @fstam Ultimately the UI thread maintains the `CancellationTokenSource` and it can cancel whenever it likes. In the meantime I have these dozens to hundreds of tasks all waiting until the tasks _they_ started are finished. If each one of those uses the `task.Start(); task.Wait();` approach, then all those dozens or hundreds of tasks are blocking dozens to hundreds of threads no?

Comment: @DavidRutten There is no UI thread.. There is a main method. Nothing is async nor awaited. Your code only has a single thread.

Comment: @fstam, yes, I'm aware that the code I posted only does _one_ thing. The thing that doesn't work as I was expecting it to. Do you want me to post the 1.4 million lines of code that do have all the complexity?

The question is; "Why doesn't Task.Wait() start the task it's called on, as implied by that MS blog post?" Did I misunderstand the post completely? Has the behaviour changed since 2009? Is the behaviour described in the post not reliable enough to work every time?

Comment: `Task.Wait` may *execute* the task, *if* it's already assigned to a scheduler. It will *not* `Start` a task that is still in the `Created` state.

Comment: @DavidRutten Obviously you don't need to post 1.4 milion lines of code. You could at least help me help you by providing a clear example af what you are trying to do. The API documentation doesn't imply executing the task. It implies waiting if it is already running.

Comment: @fstam yeah, the MSDN docs say nothing about the task being started, which is suspicious right off the bat, because it seems to contradict Stephen Toubs blog post. I guess I'll have to figure out how to inline tasks myself...

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean but here's how to run a task from a single line - await Task.Run(() => {<method>});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Task`s are generally split into two groups - "cold" tasks and "hot" tasks. "cold" tasks are tasks that have not yet been started and *are not meant to run yet*. "hot" tasks are tasks that may or may not be currently running but, importantly, if they're not running yet, they may do so at any time. They're *meant* to be running but haven't yet been assigned the resource (a thread) they need to do so.

What [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/10/15/task-wait-and-inlining/) is talking about is executing a "hot" task that hasn't otherwise had an opportunity to run. "hot" tasks are created by calling e.g. `Task.Run()`. They're also e.g. the type of `Task`s you'll receive from async methods. `new Task(...)`, on the other hand gives you "cold" tasks. Unless or until you call `Start` or moral equivalent methods on that task, it remains "cold". It's calling one of those methods explicitly that makes it "hot" instead of "cold".

Generally, you don't want to be working with "cold" tasks at all these days, which is why directly calling a `Task` constructor is frowned upon. They were really a bad experiment from before they worked out how scheduling should really work. Most modern code doesn't expect to be working with "cold" tasks at all.

The key quote from the above post is this one:

> However, if it hasn’t started executing, Wait may be able to pull the target task out of the scheduler to which it was queued and execute it inline on the current thread.

If you've not called `Start` on the task, it hasn't been queued with a scheduler - so obviously we cannot do what the above says.

Comment: Yep it all finally makes sense now. That Task.Wait() optimisation is not something to be used as an aspect in api design. Sounds like I’ll either have to start using async-await or direct inlining.

Answer (score 0):

This is the part of [the article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-wait-and-inlining/) that caused the confusion (emphasis added).

> If the Task being Wait’d on has already *started execution*, Wait has to block. However, if it hasn’t *started executing*, Wait may be able to pull the target task out of the scheduler to which it was queued and execute it inline on the current thread.

This is the description of the [`Task.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) method:

> Starts the `Task`, scheduling it for execution to the current `TaskScheduler`.

And these are the [eight different stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus) of a task's lifecycle:

```
public enum TaskStatus
{
    Created = 0, // The task has been initialized but has not yet been scheduled.
    WaitingForActivation = 1, // The task is waiting to be activated and scheduled internally by the .NET Framework infrastructure.
    WaitingToRun = 2, // The task has been scheduled for execution but has not yet begun executing.
    Running = 3, // The task is running but has not yet completed.
    WaitingForChildrenToComplete = 4, // The task has finished executing and is implicitly waiting for attached child tasks to complete.
    RanToCompletion = 5, // The task completed execution successfully.
    Canceled = 6, // The task acknowledged cancellation by throwing an OperationCanceledException with its own CancellationToken while the token was in signaled state, or the task's CancellationToken was already signaled before the task started executing.
    Faulted = 7 // The task completed due to an unhandled exception.
}
```

The article is talking implicitly about **hot** tasks that are either in the `WaitingForActivation` or in the `WaitingToRun` stage, and explains under which conditions they could be progressed internally to the `Running` stage when their `Wait` method is called. It's not talking about **cold** tasks in the `Created` stage. A task in this stage cannot be progressed without either its `Start` or `RunSynchronously` method called. In other words the .NET infrastructure never changes the temperature of a task from cold to hot automatically. This responsibility belongs 100% to the application code that created the task using the `Task` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor).

As a side note, it's worth quoting this sentence from the remarks:

> This constructor should only be used in advanced scenarios where it is required that the creation and starting of the task is separated.