# Switch new Task(()=>{ }) for Func<Task>

Tags: c#, async-await, task

In an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60980634/16241) to one of my other questions, I was told that use of `new Task(() => { })` is not something that is a normal use case.  I was advised to use `Func<Task>` instead.  I have tried to make that work, but I can't seem to figure it out.  (Rather than drag it out in the comments, I am asking a separate question here.)

My specific scenario is that I need the **Task to not start right when it is declared** and to be able to **wait for it later.**

Here is a LinqPad example using `new Task(() => { })`.  ***NOTE: This works perfectly!***  (Except that it uses `new Task`.)

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Line that I need to swap to a Func<Task> somehow.
    // note that this is "cold" not started task  
    Task startupDone = new Task(() => { });

    var runTask = DoStuff(() =>
    {
        //+++ This is where we want to task to "start"
        startupDone.Start();
    });

    //+++ Here we wait for the task to possibly start and finish. Or timeout.
    // Note that this times out at 1000ms even if "blocking = 10000" below.
    var didStartup = startupDone.Wait(1000);

    Console.WriteLine(!didStartup ? "Startup Timed Out" : "Startup Finished");

    await runTask;

    Console.Read();
}

public static async Task DoStuff(Action action)
{
    // Swap to 1000 to simulate starting up blocking
    var blocking = 1; //1000;
    await Task.Delay(500 + blocking);
    action();
    // Do the rest of the stuff...
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

I tried swapping the second line with:

```
Func<Task> startupDone = new Func<Task>(async () => { });
```

But then the lines below the comments with `+++` in them don't work right.

I swapped the `startupDone.Start()` with `startupDone.Invoke()`.

But `startupDone.Wait` needs the task.  Which is only returned in the lambda.  I am not sure how to get access to the task outside the lambda so I can `Wait` for it.

**How can use a `Func<Task>` and start it in one part of my code and do a `Wait` for it in another part of my code?**  (Like I can with `new Task(() => { })`).

Comment: The Task you want to wait on is returned from calling startupDone.Invoke()

Comment: Just `await` the started task. I see no problem

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü - I need the task to start in the lambda and have a "time out" style wait outside the boolean.  Can that we done with an `await` in there?

Comment: @JonasHøgh - Yes, but I need it outside the lambda...  To do the `Wait(1000)` call.

Comment: Does the following `Func<Task> startupDone` return a new Task all the time or the same

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü - I am not sure what you are asking...  This is just example code but I will be using it the same way in my code (to signal that start up is done or timed out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted cannot be refactored to make use of a `Func<Task>` instead of a cold task, because the method that needs to `await` the task (the `Main` method) is not the same method that controls the creation/starting of the task (the lambda parameter of the `DoStuff` method). This could make the use of the `Task` constructor legitimate in this case, depending on whether the design decision to delegate the starting of the task to a lambda is justified. In this particular example the `startupDone` is used as a synchronization primitive, to signal that a condition has been met and the program can continue. This could be achieved equally well by using a specialized synchronization primitive, like for example a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim):

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var startupSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
    Task runTask = RunAsync(startupSemaphore);
    bool startupFinished = await startupSemaphore.WaitAsync(1000);
    Console.WriteLine(startupFinished ? "Startup Finished" : "Startup Timed Out");
    await runTask;
}

public static async Task RunAsync(SemaphoreSlim startupSemaphore)
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    startupSemaphore.Release(); // Signal that the startup is done
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

In my opinion using a `SemaphoreSlim` is more meaningful in this case, and makes the intent of the code clearer. It also allows to `await` asynchronously the signal with a timeout [`WaitAsync(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync#System_Threading_SemaphoreSlim_WaitAsync_System_Int32_), which is not something that you get from a `Task` out of the box ([it is doable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout) though).

Using cold tasks may be tempting in some cases, but when you revisit your code after a month or two you'll find yourself confused, because of how rare and unexpected is to have to deal with tasks that may or may have not been started yet.

Comment: Side note: neither `await` not `.Wait` start a task (it stays cold) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156253/does-or-does-task-wait-not-start-the-task-if-it-isnt-already-running... I would have never guessed that behavior...

Comment: SemaphoreSlim worked perfectly and as you said, more clearly shows what I am trying to do.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, the type of your "do this later" object is going to become `Func<Task>`. Then, when the task is started (by invoking the function), you get back a `Task` that represents the operation:

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
  Func<Task> startupDoneDelegate = async () => { };
  Task startupDoneTask = null;

  var runTask = await DoStuff(() =>
  {
    startupDoneTask = startupDoneDelegate();
  });

  var didStartup = startupDoneTask.Wait(1000);

  Console.WriteLine(!didStartup ? "Startup Timed Out" : "Startup Finished");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  unfortunately when `startupDoneTask.Wait(1000)` is executed it throws a `NullReferenceException`  (Because the lambda has not set the task yet.)

Comment: Added the `await`. Yes, you can only call `Wait` on the task after it has been created.

Comment: Adding the `await` makes the main flow wait for the entire execution of `DoStuff()` to finish. The `startupDoneTask.Wait` call is pointless then (because not only is startup done, but so is the whole method.)  Basically, adding that changes the method to do something different from the example.

Answer (score 0):

I always try my hardest to never have blocking behavior when dealing with anything async or any type that represents potential async behavior such as `Task`. You can slightly modify your `DoStuff` to facilitate waiting on your `Action`.

```cs
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<CancellationToken,Task> startupTask = async(token)=>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
        await Task.Delay(3000, token);
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    };
    using var source = new CancellationTokenSource(2000);
    var runTask = DoStuff(() => startupTask(source.Token), source.Token);
    var didStartup = await runTask;
    Console.WriteLine(!didStartup ? "Startup Timed Out" : "Startup Finished");
    Console.Read();
}

public static async Task<bool> DoStuff(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken token)
{
    var blocking = 10000;
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(500 + blocking, token);
        await action();
    }
    catch(TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this code guarantees that startup will take at most 1000 ms as OP's code. I.e. if `blocking` is set to 10000 the whole thing will wait 10500ms till `action` has chance to check for cancellation...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, you are right, it did not timeout. I have made an edit and this now timeouts correctly, albeit due to Task.Delay, if there was actual blocking behavior, then I'm not sure how to get past that.